# Замена после символа

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

В текстовом файле есть строки:

```
112.12.34.555.123+1245.И тут текст
11.111.54.888+54544.И тут текст
333.231+554333.И тут текст
```

Как заменить первую точку (.) после знака плюс (+) на точку с запятой (;). Что бы получить результат:

```
112.12.34.555.123+1245;И тут текст
11.111.54.888+54544;И тут текст
333.231+554333;И тут текст
```

Если через StringReplace (То замена делается всех точек):

```
s  := StringReplace(s1, '.', ' ;', [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Найти и заменить.

Без проверок:

```
PlusPos := Pos('+', s);
PtPos := Pos('.', s, PlusPos); 
s[PtPos] := ';';
```

В старых версиях - `PosEx`

Comment: А вот как объявить переменные PlusPos,PtPos: string; Правильно ?

Comment: Integer. Разве в хелпе по Pos это не описано?

Comment: Аааа :) Извините я уже ... Все работает! Спасибо!